# aws s3 cp files from the root of a subdirectory without getting subfolders as well? Powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, aws-cli

`s3://bucketname/yyyymmdd/foo/bar` I have some files in the root directory and I want to copy them. I do not want to copy any subdirectories to the root (foo). I'm trying this in powershell:

```
aws s3 cp "s3://bucketname" . --recursive --exclude "*/foo/*/*" --include "foo/*.*"  --dryrun
```

or

```
aws s3 cp "s3://bucketname" . --recursive --exclude "yy*/foo/*/*" --include "foo/*.*"  --dryrun
```

I get the files in foo but I also get some files stored like `s3://bucketname/otherdirectory/otherfiles`.  I tried some alternatives:
This appears to list EVERY file in the bucket:

```
aws s3 cp "s3://bucketname" . --recursive --exclude "*/foo/*/*" --include "*/foo/*.*"  --dryrun
```

My gut says it should be

```
aws s3 cp source destination --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*/foo/*.*" --dryrun
```

meaning `/directory/*anyfilename.*anyextention` but this gives me every file recursively below `s3://bucketname/yyyymmdd/foo/`.

I'm trying to whip up a one liner without foreach patterns but I may have to resort to that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
(get-s3object -bucket bucketname | where{$_.key -like "*/foo/*"} | where{$_.key -notlike "*/foo/*/*"}).key
```

This list just the files in foo with no subfolders or subfolder files.  It does this regardless of the YYYYMMDD for the bucket.  I can now pipe this to read-s3object to get the files.

```
get-s3object -bucket bucketname | where{$_.key -like "*/foo/*"} | where{$_.key -notlike "*/foo/*/*"} | read-s3object -folder .
```